# Is my school blocking IRC connection?

Tags: irc

I am trying to connect to irc.mozilla.org and freenode and I am getting the following messages on weechat IRC client.

```
14:17:07  weechat     | irc: server mozilla created
14:17:15  mozilla     | irc: connecting to server irc.mozilla.org/6697...
14:17:16  mozilla     | irc: connected to irc.mozilla.org/6697 (63.245.216.214)
14:17:16  mozilla =!= | irc: reading data on socket: error 104 Connection reset by peer
14:17:16  mozilla     | irc: disconnecting from server...
14:17:16  mozilla     | irc: disconnected from server
14:17:16  mozilla     | irc: reconnecting to server in 10 seconds
14:17:26  mozilla     | irc: reconnecting to server...
14:17:26  mozilla     | irc: connecting to server irc.mozilla.org/6697...
14:17:26  mozilla     | irc: connected to irc.mozilla.org/6697 (63.245.216.214)
14:17:26  mozilla =!= | irc: reading data on socket: error 104 Connection reset by peer
14:17:26  mozilla     | irc: disconnecting from server...
14:17:26  mozilla     | irc: disconnected from server
14:17:26  mozilla     | irc: reconnecting to server in 20 seconds
14:17:46  mozilla     | irc: reconnecting to server...
14:17:46  mozilla     | irc: connecting to server irc.mozilla.org/6697...
14:17:46  mozilla     | irc: connected to irc.mozilla.org/6697 (63.245.216.214)
14:17:46  mozilla =!= | irc: reading data on socket: error 104 Connection reset by peer
14:17:46  mozilla     | irc: disconnecting from server...
14:17:46  mozilla     | irc: disconnected from server
14:17:46  mozilla     | irc: reconnecting to server in 40 seconds
14:18:26  mozilla     | irc: reconnecting to server...
14:18:26  mozilla     | irc: connecting to server irc.mozilla.org/6697...
14:18:26  mozilla     | irc: connected to irc.mozilla.org/6697 (63.245.216.214)
14:18:26  mozilla =!= | irc: reading data on socket: error 104 Connection reset by peer
14:18:26  mozilla     | irc: disconnecting from server...
14:18:26  mozilla     | irc: disconnected from server
14:18:26  mozilla     | irc: reconnecting to server in 1 minute, 20 seconds
14:19:14  weechat     | irc: server oftc created
14:19:19     oftc     | irc: connecting to server irc.oftc.net/6667...
14:19:36 freenode === | ========== End of backlog (5 lines) ==========
14:19:36 freenode     | irc: connecting to server chat.freenode.net/7000...
14:19:46  mozilla     | irc: reconnecting to server...
14:19:46  mozilla     | irc: connecting to server irc.mozilla.org/6697...
14:19:46  mozilla     | irc: connected to irc.mozilla.org/6697 (63.245.216.214)
14:19:46  mozilla =!= | irc: reading data on socket: error 104 Connection reset by peer
14:19:46  mozilla     | irc: disconnecting from server...
14:19:46  mozilla     | irc: disconnected from server
14:19:46  mozilla     | irc: reconnecting to server in 2 minutes, 40 seconds
```

It said connect reset. If it were refused I probably think it is blocked. But it's being reset after connected, what's going on? Packet filtering?

How do I test whether or not my school is blocking IRC client from connecting to an IRC server? I am a Linux (Ubuntu) user.

Comment: You could consider using a bouncer, or better yet, a remote shell with weechat/irssi running inside tmux/screen.